# When full build and when partial build?

Tags: c++, build, incremental-build

Hi I am trying to find out when full build is required and when partial build is sufficient.
There are many articals but I am not able to find the specific answers.

Below are my thoughts

**Full build is required when :**

1.Change in build of dependent modules.

---change in build option or using optimization techniques.

2.changes in the object layout:

---Any change in the headder file, adding and deleting of new methods in class .

---Changing object size by adding or removing of variables or virtual functions.

---Data alignment changes using pragma pack.

3.Any change in global variables

**Partial build is sufficient  when:**

1.Any change in the logic as long as it is not altering the interface specified

2.change in stack variable

Comment: This may be better off tagged as community.

Comment: I'm not sure we are using the same definition of full and partial build.  There are several cases where you do a full build and I just let `make` build what is needed to be rebuilt. For instance when I modify an header.

Comment: As long as your build environment determines the dependencies correctly, including the compiler settings file, then the simple timestamp ordering should provide the correct semantics.

Answer (score 1):

In the ideal world a full build should never be necessary, because all the build tools detecting automatically if one of their dependencies have changed.

But this is true only in the ideal world. Practically build tools are written by humans and humans

- make failures, so the tools may not take every possible change into account,
- are lazy, so the tools may not take any change into account.

For you this means you have to have some experience with your build tools. With a good written makefile may take everything into account and you rarely have to do a full build. But in the 21st century a makefile is not really state of the art any more, and they become complex very soon. Todays development environments do a fairly good job in finding dependencies, but for larger projects, you may have dependencies which are hard to put in the concept of your development environment and you will writing a script.

So there is no real answer to your question. In practise it is good to do a full rebuild for every release, then this rebuild should be done by pressing just one button. And do a partial build for daily work, since nobody wants to wait 2 hours to see if is code is compilable or not. But even in dayly work a full rebuild is sometimes neccessary because the linker/compiler/(your choice of tool here) had not recognized even the simplest change.